# Horse and snail problem.

Tags: calculus

A horse has a rubber band attached to it which can expand infinitely and is tied to a pole on the other end. At first the length of the rubber band is $l$. on the pole-side of the rubber band there is a snail. If both start walking at the same time: The horse at speed $u$ and the snail at speed $v$ with $u>v$  when will the snail catch the horse?

Comment: What does "on the pole side of the rubber band" mean? Does that mean next to the pole?

Comment: @recursiverecursion yes, it means he is at distance l from the horse, on the other end of the rubber band.

Comment: see also: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40473/generalized-worm-on-the-rubber-band-problem/), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781451/help-in-figuring-an-optimum-spider-speed/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of the rubber band at time $t$ is $l(t)=l+vt$. The fraction of the total band covered by the snake in one second at time $t$ is $\frac u{l+vt}$. We are going to integrate this from $t=0$ to $t=\infty$. If the integral is less than $1$, the snail will never reach the horse. If it is $1$ or larger, it will reach the horse. Since we have
$$
\int\frac u{l+vt}\,dt=\frac uv \ln(l+vt)
$$
and $\lim_{t\to \infty}\log(1+vt)=\infty$, the snail will catch the horse. This happens at time $t=T$ for which
$$
\int_{t=0}^{t=T}\frac u{l+vt}\,dt=1\\
\frac uv(\ln(l+vT)-\ln (l))=1\\
\ln\left(\frac{l+vT}l\right)=\frac vu\\
T=\frac{l(e^{\frac vu}-1)}v
$$

Comment: @user4140, whoops, i changed the $l$ to a $1$ somewhere. I'll fix it

Comment: @user4140, yes, I fixed it.

Comment: @user4140 Apparently, I messed up more than I thought. Mathematica's $1$ and $l$ aren't as distinguishable as they could be.